sacct MaxRSS ending with +
I used the command
sacct --format="CPUTimeraw,MaxRSS"
to get the MaxRSS of my slurm job.
However, the result looks like this:

MaxRSS
128340475+

What to make of this? Why is the MaxRSS ending with +?
Which number is the final and can I get the result in Mb instead of kb?
